# aptly lists snapshots that it then cannot find

Tags: apt

I'm not sure what's going on here or how to remedy. I want to delete the old snapshot. There are several more of these that are in the same state.

```
# aptly snapshot list  -raw | grep bionic-backports-202108131557
bionic-backports-202108131557  

# aptly snapshot list -raw | grep bionic-backports-202108131557 | xargs -n1 aptly snapshot show
ERROR: unable to show: snapshot with name bionic-backports-202108131557 not found

# aptly snapshot list -raw | grep bionic-backports-202108131557 | xargs -n1 aptly snapshot drop
ERROR: unable to drop: snapshot with name bionic-backports-202108131557 not found
```

My expectation would be that any snapshot that `aptly snapshot list` lists could be found and acted upon.

*(I don't have enough reputation to create the 'aptly' tag. A tag is required so I chose 'apt' though this isn't an 'apt' question.)*

Comment: also tried `aptly db cleanup` which didn't resolve the problem.

Comment: and `aptly db recover` ...